Video device not stopping in C# .NET
In the following code the videoCaptureDevice couldn't stop:
videoCaptureDevice = new VideoCaptureDevice(filterInfoCollection[cboCamera.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
videoCaptureDevice.NewFrame += VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame;

videoCaptureDevice.Start();
videoCaptureDevice.Stop();

VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame code is the following:
private void VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    try
    {
        if (pic.InvokeRequired)
        {
            pic.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
            {
                pic.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            pic.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

The exception is

System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Thread abort is not supported on this platform.'

I'm using .NET 8 and Windows Forms.

Are you using this?

As described in the documentation:

Since the method aborts background thread, its usage is highly not
preferred and should be done only if there are no other options. The
correct way of stopping camera is signaling it stop and then waiting
for background thread's completion.

Therefore, consider using the SignalToStop method.
videoCaptureDevice = new VideoCaptureDevice(filterInfoCollection[cboCamera.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
videoCaptureDevice.NewFrame += VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame;

videoCaptureDevice.Start();
videoCaptureDevice.SignalToStop();

